# Pentaho Text File Input Have 2 Line in 1 Row

Tags: database, input, text, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

So I have text file like this:

```
Code   Prod_Name    Color   Stock        Price
201    Long         Lime    50           3900
       Shirt        Green
202    Short Skull  Dark    100          3900
       Shirt        Red
```

And I want to be read like this:

```
Code   Prod_Name          Color         Stock        Price
201    Long Shirt         Lime Green    50           3900
202    Short Skull Shirt  Dark Red      100          3900
```

So how to achieve that only in Pentaho?

I have try text input using wrapped lines, but it doesn't seems the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricky one. Don't think there is a standard step to achieve this. Is a pretty rare case imo. But you can do it... Just load the file and during load have rownumbers added. Then seperate even from uneven with a filter. Do rownumber-1 at the even side, and join the two sets together on rownumber. Then concat both versions of each field in the new set. (don't forget to trim fields in case a column doesn't have 2 lines, and the seperator space is added for no reason)

[image: Sollution]

Even better would be to repeat the ID number ("Code" in this case) in the insert and then to connect on this field:

[image: Alternative]

Result:

[image: Result_image]

Comment: Cool! It's work, and it will help me to another case of data, thank you