# Pentaho Text File Input Wrapped Lines

Tags: database, input, text, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

So I have text file like this:

```
       1  23/08/17  01:29:41 40    0210    6019004522702859          10,000,000.00                 0.00   7000   0000JH     005771
   APP  00    00    006716   30    S1G9986387         123-6521071921                                      BEKASI       
       2  23/08/17  03:38:33 40    0210    6019004521299402           3,300,000.00                 0.00   7000   0000VG     011250
   APP  00    00    280110   30    S1ACMB9503         123-8225022594                                                   
       3  23/08/17  04:45:00 40    0210    6019004508194352           5,000,000.00                 0.00   7000   000117     014015
   APP  00    00    282177   30    S1ACMB9503         123-7025047324                                                   
       4  23/08/17  05:02:00 40    0210    6019004521299402             700,000.00                 0.00   7000   00014D     015036
   APP  00    00    282944   30    S1ACMB9503         123-8225022594                                                   
       5  23/08/17  06:03:30 40    0210    6019004521269470           3,670,000.00                 0.00   7000   0001RT     024220
   APP  00    00    289871   30    S1ACMB9503         123-1122501295                                                   
       6  23/08/17  06:08:26 40    0210    6019002662198912           1,000,000.00                 0.00   7000   0001UR     025341
   APP  00    00    290705   30    S1ACMB9503         123-1152511520                                                   
       7  23/08/17  06:27:51 40    0210    6019002674210655          15,000,000.00                 0.00   7000   00029J     030585
   APP  00    00    294279   30    S1ACMB9503         123-1132116951                                                   
       8  23/08/17  06:38:59 40    0210    6019002666264330             900,000.00                 0.00   7000   0002LA     001833
   APP  00    00    296752   30    S1ACMB9503         123-1121109898                                                   
       9  23/08/17  06:54:58 40    0210    6019004009652312             200,000.00                 0.00   7000   00039O     008300
   APP  00    00    000597   30    S1G997Z73P         123-1025591061                                      PONTIANAK    
      10  23/08/17  07:01:29 40    0210    6019004521630044             875,000.00                 0.00   7000   0003KZ     011350
```

[I use this setting on text Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2zT6.png)

I want it to shows like this:

```
1  23/08/17  01:29:41 40    0210    6019004522702859          10,000,000.00                 0.00   7000   0000JH     005771 APP  00    00    006716   30    S1G9986387         123-6521071921                                      BEKASI       
2  23/08/17  03:38:33 40    0210    6019004521299402           3,300,000.00                 0.00   7000   0000VG     011250 APP  00    00    280110   30    S1ACMB9503         123-8225022594
```

But when I run, the result is like this:
[Its not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewt5w.png)

So how to achieve that only in Pentaho?

Comment: The answer is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76776497/pentaho-text-file-input-have-2-line-in-1-row)

Comment: You can indeed use the same sollution here too, but it is even easier to use the wrapped lines option in text input here, since the columns are seperatly. Both should work.